# How to get the response from a bean in jsf ajax call using f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

Hi i am working on jsf `f:ajax` i it worked for me when i have done the validations with in the page using ajax. but now i wanted to get the response from a Managed bean method that is called on as a ajax listener.

I m not able to get the response back in any of the format.any body please help me.
Here is the code

register.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="Full Name:" escape="false" />
        <h:inputText value="#{display.user}" required="true" label="User ID"
            id="username">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Za-z]*[\.][A-Za-z]*"></f:validateRegex>
            <!--            <f:validator validatorId="com.jason.jsf.custom.Myvalidator"></f:validator> -->
            <f:ajax render="usernameMessage outputMessage" event="blur" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="usernameMessage" for="username" style="color:red;" />

        <h:outputText value="Email:" escape="false" />
        <h:inputText value="#{display.email}" required="true" id="EmailID"
            label="Email ID"
            validatorMessage="#{display.email} is not valid email">
            <f:validateRegex
                pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
            <f:ajax render="EmailIDmsg" event="blur"
                listener="#{display.getMessage}" onevent="fun" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="EmailIDmsg" for="EmailID" />
```

script.js

```
  function fun(e){

    var xmlDoc,x,txt,i;


    alert("text"+e.responseText);

    alert("XML"+e.responseXML);
}
```

Method in Display.java a managed bean with name display contians a field email with all the setters and getters

```
  public String getMessage(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("hai this is listener method");
        System.out.println(e.getComponent().getId());
        System.out.println(email);

                return email;   
    }
```

I using JSF 2.0 Mojarra 2.0.3

Comment: What a strange approach. [What problem exactly are you trying to solve for which you incorrectly thought that this all would be the proper solution?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Don't you just need to add a faces message to the context?

Comment: Thank you @BalusC. The example i used may be not appropriate. i just wanted to read the response using ajax in different formats. or in one word whatever may be the issue how do i get the response back in java script function example in XML format (responseXML)

Comment: You still haven't elaborated what exactly you need it for. So it's still impossible to bake a good answer to that. On a second thought, perhaps you just want  a RESTful webservice controller instead of a JSF MVC controller? In any case, it wouldn't be a bad idea to take a pause on the project, pick a sane JSF book and carefully work through it in order to properly grasp the fundamental concepts.